# How to exclude row in one-to-many relationship between tables (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, Products and ProductTags  (I also have table Tags which is not part of the problem)

My query is

```
SELECT
product.id
FROM
Products JOIN ProductTags ON Products.id = ProductTags.product_id
WHERE ProductTags.tag_id = 10  and ProductTags.tag_id <> 20
```

Table ProductTags is one-to-many connection between product_id and tag_id, if it's called like that. Let's say that whole ProductTags table is:

| product_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 777 | 10 |
| 777 | 20 |
| 888 | 10 |
| 888 | 30 |

what I get as an output from my query is 777 and  888. But I want to exclude products which have tag #20.
In real query I also join with other tables (also I need to have access to other fields of Products table), so I CAN'T get proper result using only ProductTags table! I am aware that I could do it like

```
SELECT product_id ProductTags WHERE tag_id = 10
```

but this WON'T be proper solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use aggregation.

```
SELECT product_id id
       FROM producttags
       WHERE tag_id IN (10,
                        20)
       GROUP BY product_id
       HAVING max(tag_id) = 10;
```

Another one uses `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT pt1.product_id
       FROM producttag pt1
       WHERE pt1.tag_id = 10
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM producttag pt2
                                    WHERE pt2.product_id = pt1.product_id
                                          AND pt2.tag_id = 20);
```

Note that the join of `product` isn't needed to only get the product IDs, unless there's no proper foreign key constraint on `producttags.product_id`.

Comment: Thank you! usage of NOT EXISTS helped me, now it works as indented!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT product.id
FROM Products 
JOIN ProductTags ON Products.id = ProductTags.product_id
GROUP BY product.id
HAVING SUM(ProductTags.tag_id = 10) > 0 -- at least one
   AND SUM(ProductTags.tag_id = 20) = 0 -- none
```

This form allows any amount of simple or complex conditions.

For example:

```sql
-- strictly one row with tag_id = 30
   AND SUM(ProductTags.tag_id = 30) = 1
-- at least one tag_id 40 or 50
   AND SUM(ProductTags.tag_id IN (40, 50)) > 0
-- ... and so on
```